# how to connect the UITabbar to viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't use UITabbarController,I just add the UITabbar in ViewController.I know when we use UITabbarController,we will create one array which contain viewcontrollers,so when we tap the tab,will show the specific viewcontroller,but the UITabbar just can add UITabbarItems,so how to connect the viewcontroller to the Tab?just like UITabbarController. thank you in advance.

Comment: So you're trying to do a Tab bar based app, without using a UITabBarController, what's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a [`UITabBarDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to your `UITabBar`:

```
self.tabbar.delegate = self; 
// make sure you declared self to be a UITabBarDelegate in your header
```

Then implement:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
  // item is the selected tab bar item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your view controller implement the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol.  Then set your tab bar's `delegate` property to point at your instance of your view controller.  In your view controller class you can implement the `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method, which will get called whenever the user selects an item on your tab bar.

However, if you intend to use your tab bar to switch between different view controllers you should use a `UITabBarController` -- that's what it was designed to do.